# Send an image file from Raspberry Pi to iPhone via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, node.js, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to send an image file from a Raspberry Pi to an iOS device. I know file transferring isn't allowed with iPhone Bluetooth.

Is their a way to send the image as a base64 string from the Raspberry Pi to an iPhone? I have tried sending a base64 string via Bluetooth from Raspberry Pi, but since the string is very large, the Pi is not able to send the complete string.

I am using bleno Node.js library.

Comment: You would need to write an app on receive the image

Comment: Are you restricted to retrieving the file through Bluetooth or can you access via the Network?

Comment: Did anyone find any solution? Please send if any...